# Sum of nil right ideals

Tags: ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Is an arbitrary sum of nil (nilpotent) right ideals a nil (nilpotent) right ideal?

If $I=\sum I_i$ is a sum of nil ideals then each element $x$ of $I$ is a finite sum $x=x_1+...+x_n$ of elements $x_k\in I_k$ a power ${x_k}^{p_k}$of each of which is zero. But, since each power of $x$ is a finite sum constituting of  summands of the form $∏{x_i}^{t_i}  $( of course, in this product the $x_i$'s may be repeated with different powers), I guess that one could choose the power of $x$ so "big" that it be annihilated.

Is my guess true? How?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're in noncommutative setting, it seems to be hopeless as we cannot change the order of multiplication to get a form $\prod x_i^{p_i}$(but also I cannot give an example right now).

Comment: @cjackal Yes, I edited my explanations.

Comment: This does not really answer your question, but in general a sum of nilpotent elements is not nilpotent. As an example in $M_2(k)$, take a non-zero strict upper triangular and a non-zero strict lower triangular matrix. This does not means that it won't work if the elements come from nilpotent *ideals*, but it shows that the argument is going to be a little subtle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the arbitrary sum of nilpotent right ideals nilpotent?

The counterexample writes itself: Take $R=F[x_1,x_2,\ldots]/(\{x_n^n\mid n\in \Bbb N\})$ for a field $F$. While the individual ideals $(x_i)$ are nilpotent, their sum is merely a nil ideal.

> Is the arbitrary sum of nil right ideals nil?

This is not even known for *finite* sums. The statement "the sum of any two nil right ideals is a nil right ideal" is one of the equivalent formulations of the [Koethe conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6the_conjecture) which is still unsolved.

Comment: And why is the sum in your counterexample not nilpotent?

Comment: @karparvar there are obviously elements of arbitrarily high index of nilpotency.